# Issues with installing mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mysql2

I am trying to install mysql2 gem in my windows machine and I get the following error. What should I do?

```
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.10.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib


Gem files will remain installed in D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.10 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mysql2 version list](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2/versions) doesn't have an `x86-mingw32` version for `0.3.10`. I suggest you give `0.3.9` a try with `gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.9`.